# Does a PHP exception stop execution?

Tags: php, exception

```
<?php
     function some_function($arg) {
         if($filter->check_for_safe_input($arg)) {
             throw new Exception("Hacking Attempt");
         }
         do_some_database_stuff($arg);
     }
 ?>
```

In the above code example, does `do_some_database_stuff` ever get called if `check_for_safe_input` fails, or does the exception stop the function running? It's something I've never quite been sure of, and usually I just stick functions like `do_some_database_stuff` in an else statement to be sure, but this tends to lead to hugely nested functions.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes, uncaught exceptions result in fatal errors that stop the execution of the script. So the `do_some_database_stuff` function will not be called if an exception is thrown.  You can read more about exceptions in [this article](http://www.hiremasonwolf.com/?p=93).

Comment: What if it is caught in the function calling this one? Does the rest of this function ever get run then?

Comment: No, once you throw an exception the function execution is stopped (as if you returned some result) and the exception bubbles through the call stack until it finds a `catch` statement.

Comment: No, execution resumes in the catching function; you can't (in PHP) resume execution from where an exception stopped it.

Comment: @bobince, actually, it seems better that way. why would I want execution to continue, once an exception was thrown?

Comment: @aditya: indeed, that's the generally-desired way exceptions work in all languages. A continuable exception would be an interesting language feature, though. You could use it for warnings, where a caller up the stack could decide whether an warning-exception is serious or ignorable, or as a co-routine-like construct.

Answer (score 15):

Have a look at the PHP manual on exceptions.

> When an exception is thrown, code
> following the statement will not be
> executed, and PHP will attempt to find
> the first matching catch block. If an
> exception is not caught, a PHP Fatal
> Error will be issued with an "Uncaught
> Exception ..." message, unless a
> handler has been defined with
> set_exception_handler().

[php.net/exceptions](https://www.php.net/exceptions)

So yes, the rest of the function is not being executed, a fatal error occurs instead.
If you catch the exception, execution of the script continues in the corresponding catch block, everything "between" the function which throws an exception and the catch block is not executed.

Answer (score 5):

An exception, if not catched, will end script execution.

See the [PHP manual chapter on Exceptions](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)